# Issue with HTML Simple Dom and Mysql insert

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm a beginning programmer who is trying to capture data from this [source](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/boilermaker-tailgate-chili/detail.aspx?event8=1&prop24=SR_Title&e8=Quick%20Search&event10=1&e7=Recipe%20Hub)

Here's the specific part I'm trying to capture:

```
<ul class="ingredient-wrap">

            <li id="liIngredient" data-ingredientid="3914" data-grams="907.2">
                <label>
                    <span class="checkbox-formatted"><input id="cbxIngredient" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CenterColumnPlaceHolder$recipeTest$recipe$ingredients$rptIngredientsCol1$ctl01$cbxIngredient" /></span>
                    <p class="fl-ing" itemprop="ingredients">
                        <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">2 pounds</span>
                        <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">ground beef chuck</span>

                    </p>
                </label>
            </li>

            <li id="liIngredient" data-ingredientid="5838" data-grams="454">
                <label>
                    <span class="checkbox-formatted"><input id="cbxIngredient" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CenterColumnPlaceHolder$recipeTest$recipe$ingredients$rptIngredientsCol1$ctl02$cbxIngredient" /></span>
                    <p class="fl-ing" itemprop="ingredients">
                        <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">1 pound</span>
                        <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">bulk Italian sausage</span>

                    </p>
                </label>
            </li>

            <li id="liIngredient" data-ingredientid="10429" data-grams="1278">
                <label>
                    <span class="checkbox-formatted"><input id="cbxIngredient" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CenterColumnPlaceHolder$recipeTest$recipe$ingredients$rptIngredientsCol1$ctl03$cbxIngredient" /></span>
                    <p class="fl-ing" itemprop="ingredients">
                        <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">3 (15 ounce) cans</span>
                        <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">chili beans, drained</span>

                    </p>
                </label>
            </li>
```

Each li contains two sets of words, for example: **3 (15 ounce) cans** and **chili beans, drained** I'm trying to use a foreach loop to grab the two set of words from each li, and then combine and save into a database.

Here's my code:

```
foreach($html->find(".ingredient-wrap", 0)->children as $e){
              $ingredients = $e->plaintext;
              echo trim($ingredients);
              $hostname = 'localhost';
              $username = '********';
              $password = '*******';
              $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=*********", $username, $password);
              $sql = ("INSERT INTO ingredients (recipe_id, ingredientname) VALUES (?, ?)");
              $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
              $q->execute(array($recipe_id,$ingredients));
          }
```

The problem with this is that after inserting into the database, the value for each ingredientname is **...**, even though if you echo out `echo $ingredients."<br/>"` you are presented with a list of the combined word with a space after it.

Thanks for any and all help! If you have any questions or need more clarifying, I'm here to reply!

Comment: @MarcB, Sorry, added some more to the question

Comment: getting a "list" is normal. you're using innertext to get the ingredients. essentially you're doing `striptags()` on the html that contains the ingredients, leaving you with just some bare text. you should be looping over each ingredient tag separately.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks @MarcB, Problem fixed. Would you mind making it an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a "list" is normal. You're using `->innertext` to get the ingredients. Essentially you're doing `striptags()` on the html that contains the ingredients, leaving you with just some bare text. You should be looping over each ingredient tag separately.

Answer (score -1):

Could try regex...

```
preg_match_all('/<span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">(.*)<\/span>\s+<span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">(.*)<\/span>/', $ingredients, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">2 pounds</span>
                    <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">ground beef chuck</span>
        [1] => <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">1 pound</span>
                    <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">bulk Italian sausage</span>
        [2] => <span id="lblIngAmount" class="ingredient-amount">3 (15 ounce) cans</span>
                    <span id="lblIngName" class="ingredient-name">chili beans, drained</span>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2 pounds
        [1] => 1 pound
        [2] => 3 (15 ounce) cans
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => ground beef chuck
        [1] => bulk Italian sausage
        [2] => chili beans, drained
    )

)
```

so:

```
echo $matches[2][0].": ".$matches[1][0];
```

will give:

```
ground beef chuck: 2 pounds
```

Comment: Why would OP use regexes when there's already a perfectly valid DOM parser in play?